# Angular Data that does not affect the view: use directive, object, or function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance

I have a repeated set of API calls in an Angular controller.

The relevant data is of course the API URI, POST or GET, some header data, and JSON objects.   The API call always returns a JSON object.

I started to use a Directive but that seems most relevant for data that is used with $scope (e. g. in the View).  This data runs under the radar and might eventually generate data used in the view but most usually not and most usually not in a way that can be abstracted.

So: Does this mean I shouldn't use a directive?  If I don't use a directive, would it be better to use a JS Object (seems more modular) or Function (seems more variable friendly) to handle this code?

Yes, I get that objects can contain functions, but functions can also contain callbacks so...looking for kind of a "best practices" here.  In terms of modularity and flexibility.

Comment: Use a factory, service or provider.  This is the Angular way to group functionality that does not directly have to do with a view.

Comment: @DavinTryon so provider would be out because "You should use the Provider recipe only when you want to expose an API for application-wide configuration that must be made before the application starts" which is not the case.  I will give you answer credit for "factory or service" if you'd like to write it up...

Comment: factories and services are made out of providers.  Providers are the *most* flexible way to create an Angular-aware object.

Comment: Hm...I get that but can't really reconcile that with  the second part of the comment there which is from the Angular docs.  "Factories or services" seems like a more specific answer, maybe what I need is something *less* flexible.

Comment: Yes, a service will probably do nicely in the circumstance you describe.  But, since you don't give very specific information, it is hard to give you a complete answer.

Comment: Um so I say "I need to make API calls," give examples of the kinds of information I need to provide to make these calls, and then give examples of the kind of information the API calls return.  How much more specific do you need me to be?

Comment: I didn't downvote the question ;), But usually code samples go a long way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78150/discussion-between-dave-kaye-and-davin-tryon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create Angular service for that.
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Your service will contain a method, lets say "getResults" which will make an API call and return either data or a promise (`$http`). Then you can inject you service to your controller and use that method to get the data and assign it to `$scope`.

An Angular service is certainly preferred to a more general JavaScript one because it allows you to take greater advantage of Angular's scope and other such things.  Between Angular's Factory, Service, and Providers, a Service is the most in line with what you're trying to do since a Factory is too basic and generally used to solve smaller problems while a Provider is used -- as it says in the Angular docs -- "only when you want to expose an API for application-wide configuration that must be made before the application starts."  Which is not what you're trying to do.

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question.  Can you say *why* a service is the best object (instead of a factory or provider or http interceptor or ...)?

Comment: @DavinTryon Why are you down voting people answers and telling them they didn't answer the question without leaving an answer yourself?

Comment: @JacobFinamore :) down voting is used to indicate that the answer would not be useful for others.  If the answer is good, then I'll upvote.  The answerer has the option to improve the answer, and then I'll reverse the downvote.  This is just the way to give feedback.  It has nothing to do with my wanting to answer.

Comment: @DavinTryon But your not helping at all, if you know the answer then answer it and stop wasting time down voting.. that just doesn't make since and i know how the voting system works, and you not using it properly.

Comment: Hey, I got downvoted twice just for asking the question...tough crowd on S. O.  :-)